# How to configure TYPO3 extension over a backend module?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I'm developing an extension for TYPO3 8.7 that queries an API for some data.
The frontend part works, although the API is called live at the moment.

Now **I'd like to build a little backend module in which the integrator can at least manage the API credentials.** Maybe also storage PIDs and other settings.

I guess storing data like these is usually done using TypoScript(?), but it would be nice to have a interface for storing settings of all kinds.

I rather guess I could create a database table and access it in the backend and frontend on a low level.

But before I do so I'd like to ensure that there is no other, designated way to do so. Maybe interact with the settings array somehow or whatnot.

I thought that storing configuration data would be a common usecase for backend modules. But I could not find any example for this.

Am I mislead about the usage of backend modules somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TYPO3 Provides a Lot of Configuration Options.

**in the Extension Manager**
this allows you to set settings on a Systemwide Basis.
allows you to Set extension settings. using the `ext_conf_template.txt` this is easy for extension developers. and only accessible by admins.  https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationOptions/Index.html

**Typoscrip Contants**
this allows you to set configuration on a page basis, this is a great choice if you setup different settings on diffrent pages. or have a mutlipe sites in one TYPO3 Installation. there is an Interface "Constants Editor" in the Template Module which allows editors to set the settings of the constants.

**Plugin / Flexform** 
the most common way an editor configures some settings. but they have to repeat them for every plugin.

**Backend Modules**
Backend modules are Designed for mor Complex task like manageing a News workflow. or giving inside-view into some process (status reports etc.) of cours they could be used to just store some simple settings. but its uncommen. and clutters the TYPO3 Backend Interface.

**AdditionalConfiguration.php / ext_localconf.php** this allows you to set very Low Level Configuration. if your configuration needs to be Availible only to Developer or needs to be Present in an Eary Bootstrapping Phase of TYPO3 this is a good choice

Comment: In the extension Manager seems like a suitable option. I'll look into that. I'd also like to manage cronjobs in the BE module. But that's not high priority.

Comment: See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/scheduler/8.7/ for cronjob handling in TYPO3 8 backend.

Comment: You might also add site configuration for newer TYPO3 versions

Answer (score -1):

I your case, I would create a simple backend module and store the credentials in the Registry. This is easy to explain to the customer and you have the possibility to give access to that module to special user groups. By using the registry there's no need to create custom Tables.

Guide on how to create a backend module : https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/10-Outlook/2-Backend-modules.html

Guide on the Registry: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/SystemRegistry/Index.html